# db.collection.update() throws 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: meteor

I have this server side method (Meteor method) that successfully finds a document by the ID that it is passed, but when I go to issue a mongo `.update()`, I get an internal server error (500).

```
setToggle: function(detailId){
    var checked_detail = detailsCollection.findOne({_id: detailId});

    checked_detail.update({$set: {checkboxStatus: 'toggle'}});
}
```

Here is where I initially call the method on the client to create the document:

```
'submit form': function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var detailFormData = {
        detail: $(ev.target).find('[name = detail]').val(),
        parentId: $(ev.target).find('[name = parentId]').val(),
        checkboxStatus: ''
    }

    Meteor.call('addDetail', detailFormData);
}
```

And here is that server insert method, so you can see the model:

```
 addDetail: function(detailFormData){
    if(! Meteor.userId()){
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }

    detailsCollection.insert({
        detail: detailFormData.detail,
        parentId: detailFormData.parentId,
        checkboxStatus: detailFormData.checkboxStatus  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update syntax is wrong : you're retrieving the Mongo document and then trying to call the `update` operation on the resulting plain JS object instead of calling the method on the collection itself.

Rewrite your code like this :

```
setToggle: function(detailId){
  detailsCollection.update(detailId,{
    $set: {checkboxStatus: 'toggle'}
  });
}
```

The Mongo Collection update syntax takes two (mandatory) parameters :

- a Mongo selector to identify which documents in the collection should be updated (on the client using minimongo you're only allowed to modify documents by `_id`).
- a Mongo modifier object to specify how the matching documents should be modified.

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update